# how to cancel onAuthStateChanged on createUserWithEmailAndPassword

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to cancel onAuthStateChanged when admin user creating new user with createUserWithEmailAndPassword is it possible ?

my code

admin:

```
   firebase
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        userData.userNameData.email,
        userData.userNameData.password
      )
```

global listener

```
  const isLogin = async () => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async function (user) {
      if (user) {
```

Comment: Hey Vitaly. Did you make any progress on this? I tried to help with an answer below. Did you have a chance to check that out and try it?

Answer (score 1):

When you subscribe by calling [`onAuthStateChanged`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onauthstatechanged)  it returns a function that you can use to unsubscribe that listener.

So:

```
unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async function (user) {
  ...
```

And then later:

```
unsubscribe();
```